# Passing as a parameter or creating an instance. Which is a good programming practice?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, instance

I have `class A` from which I need to pass an `Object obj` to `function func2` in `class B`. The `obj` is required in `func2` of class B.

```
class A {
   Object obj;
   .
   .
   public void func1() {
        B b = new B(obj);
        b.func2();
   }
}
```

or

```
class A {
   Object obj;
   .
   .
   public void func1() {
        B b = new B();
        b.func2(obj);
   }
}
```

I have usage of `obj` in `class B` only in `func2`.
Which is good programming practice either to pass the `obj` as parameter to `func2` or create an instance of `Object` in class B and initialize `Object` in the constructor of class B. Or it doesn't make difference using either methods? 
Appreciate any inputs on this.

**UPDATE**

To clarify my use case, `Class A` configures `HttpClient` and passes the instance of `HttpClient` to `Class B`. `func2` in `Class B` executes the `HttpRequest` and returns the response. Is there a need to maintain  `HttpClient` as instance variable in `Class B` or just pass it as parameter to `func2`. Yes, I have to create a new Instance of `B` everytime in `func1` according to the design.

Comment: Depends entirely on whether you need `obj` to be kept around, or if you only care about it for the duration of `func2()`.

Comment: Indeed. Is it logically part of the state of `B` or not? Might you call `func2` on the same instance several times and want to give it different objects to work with? This question is too vague to be answered at the moment.

Comment: @azurefrog : I need it only for the duration of func2. Thats what i meant by 'I have usage of obj in class B only in func2'.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I will have only one instance of `B` for an instance of `A` and one call to `func2`. Thats is why I haven't mentioned anything about multiple calls. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Well it's still hopelessly vague, as we don't know whether it's logically part of the state of B. It's context-sensitive, and you haven't provided any context. I very much doubt that your classes are actually A and B or that your method is called func2. The real names would give information about the context...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ofcourse not. This is just an example. There is nothing to do with context and the function name. Its a straight forward question.

Comment: "There is nothing to do with context" - sorry, but that's just *not* the case. Some things are inherently part of the state of an object - in which case they should be fields, and some things are inherently part of the information about an operation - in which case they should be parameters.

Comment: @Maverick: Well what is `B` meant to represent? Does it even have to be an instance method? What other state does the object have, if any?

Answer (score 2):

**Constructors are used to initialize the fields of a class**, so if you are passing `obj` to the constructor of class `B`, then `obj` should be a field inside class B i.e., `obj` maintains HAS-A relationship with `B`.

The other case you mentioned is that when you pass `obj` as a method (like `func2`) argument, which you typically use it inside `func2` computations.

So, you need to check whether `obj` makes sense to be as a field of class B or not so that it can be initialized as part of the constructor. So, it all depends upon the design of class `B`.

Also, to answer to your question is, just think about the relationship between `obj` and `class B` in the object oriented world,more importantly, **if you take classes like `A`, `B`, obj, etc.. you can't apply/understand the object oriented concepts easily**. **Rather, consider the real world classes and objects** like `class BankAccount` or `class Product` or `class Machine`, etc..

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are putting my question in a descriptive way. Because question is which way is better and you are explaining what I need to do in `Class B` depending on the method I choose. And design of `Class B` doesn't depend on how I get `obj` as its used only in `func2` and only once. I hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: Again, the answer to this is, just think about the relationship between `obj` and `class B` in the object oriented world, also, if you take general classes like A, B, obj, etc.. you can't understand the concept easily. Rather, take the real world classes and objects.

Comment: If this helps, you can accept my answer

Comment: Updated the question with my use case. Any more justification with that?

Answer (score -1):

Since you only use obj in func2 I would suggest passing it to the method as a parameter. This will allow the object to be garbage collected sooner instead of waiting for B to be destroyed. However, if the method is frequently used then it may decrease performance. It is impossible to tell with the information provided.

You can use bench-marking to test the performance and compare the two approaches in your project.

Comment: JVM automatic take care of garbage collection.